# Problems trying to change from Framework 4.0 to 3.5 .NET

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, frameworks, windows-forms-designer, downgrade

I have a project done with. NET Framework 4, and I need to add some libraries which work on the Framework 3.5, so I changed my project to Framework 3.5, now the project recognizes the libraries, but it shows an error similar to this:

**Error 2 Object reference not set to an instance of an object.**

and this is in each. resx I have in my project, how can I resolve this?

Comment: you need to fix all the compilation errors. No silver bullet

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this will work for you...

> 1. Open Form in Designer and make needed GUI changes. Close designer and save
> 2. Compile project and receive RESX compile error (only forms with Imagelist should have this problem)
> 3. Double-click resx compile error to open resx file.
> 4. Scroll to top of imagestream.
> 5. Edit the top line of the Image stream: AAEAAAD/////AQAAAAAAAAAMAgAAAFdTeXN0ZW0uV2luZG93cy5Gb3JtcywgVmVyc2lvbj00LjAuMC4w
>    TO
>    AAEAAAD/////AQAAAAAAAAAMAgAAAFdTeXN0ZW0uV2luZG93cy5Gb3JtcywgVmVyc2lvbj0yLjAuMC4w
> 6. Close and save resx file and recompile.
>
> **NOTE: the only difference are the characters at end "j00LjAuMC4w' to "j0yLjAuMC4w"

Got this solution from [Microsoft Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/532584/error-when-compiling-resx-file-seems-related-to-beta2-bug-5252020) website. Thanks to them.